# getting the list of all checked items from a Listview with customAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I have got a listview with custom adapter. I have checkbox with textview in my row.

Following is my getView method

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.filters, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
            final ViewHolder finalViewHolder = viewHolder;
            viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
                    list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.label, viewHolder.text);
            convertView.setTag(R.id.check, viewHolder.checkbox);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position);

        viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return convertView;
    }
```

How can I be able to get the list of all checked items in Checkbox? I tried using SparseBooleanArray but still I wasn't be able to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all checked items from listview Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464570/getting-all-checked-items-from-listview-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would try to do: 
1. Create StateList 
3. Set ChangeCheckListener to null
 
2. Load item state from list
3. Create ChangeCheckListener -listen to onChange action and save it to a list